# From jquery back to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a pure JavaScript equivalent of this Jquery code:
because the use of libraries isnt allowed in my current project,

File handler.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#some_button").click(function(){

  alert('ok. works');

 });

});
```

File index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="handler.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<button id="some_button">Btn</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put this in your `handler.js` file:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('some_button').addEventListener('click',
    function() {
       alert('ok. works');
    }, true);
};
```

NB: this won't work on older IE versions that don't support `addEventListener`.  You *could* be lazy and use the DOM0 `element.onclick` method instead.

Comment: @metal_fan ah, yes.  You can't do `document.body` because it doesn't exist yet...

Answer (score 0):

```
 function buttonClick() {
     alert('ok. works');
}
```

File index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<head>
<body>
<button id="some_button" onclick="buttonClick()">Btn</button>
</body>

</html>
```